# Glass Development Kit installed but not found by Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, google-glass

I get a Gradle Sync error saying "Failed to set up SDK": Error: Module 'app': platform 'Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19' not found.

I have Glass Development Kit Preview from Android API 19 installed. My build.gradle(Module: app) is updated to reflect that:

```
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19'
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
```

I've looked at similar problems and I seem to have my build.gradle set up properly. How can I get the Gradle Sync to recognize my GDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the base build Tools for GDK:

`android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
}`

Download Android 4.4.2 or API 19.

Or try using this  [link](https://www.toptal.com/google-glass/building-your-first-glass-app-a-tutorial-for-aspiring-google-glass-developers) . It creates a new project of GDK, and you can check how gradle looks afterwards.